# How to configure multiple I/O Expander PCF8574a in a device tree?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, i2c, device-tree

I am currently adding an I/O Expander PCF8574a in my device tree am335x-boneblack.dts. I have two I/O expander, one at 0x38 and another at 0x39.

The code below works fine for a single expander but if I add PCF8574a with address 0x39 in the similar manner, it shows an error.

```
&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins_default>;
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <400000>;

pcf8574a: pcf8574a@38 {
    compatible = "nxp,pcf8574a";
    reg = <0x38>;
    gpio-controller;            
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
};
```

};

Error log :

> "Duplicate label 'pcf8574a' on /ocp/i2c@4802a000/pcf8574a@39 and /ocp/i2c@4802a000/pcf8574a@38" 
>   which I completely understand.

But I dont know how to add another node or say sub node to make this work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this

```
&i2c1 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins_default>;
    status = "okay";
    clock-frequency = <400000>;

pcf8574a_38: pcf8574a@38 {
    compatible = "nxp,pcf8574a";
    reg = <0x38>;
    gpio-controller;            
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
};
pcf8574a_39: pcf8574a@39 {
    compatible = "nxp,pcf8574a";
    reg = <0x39>;
    gpio-controller;            
    #gpio-cells = <2>;
};
};
```

Comment: Hello @yashC , I had implemented it the same way, and yes thanks for your update

Comment: the same way as in your answer